# Cannot auto mount NAS running samba on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, samba, automount, nas

I have tried to auto mount my NAS running samba with the following modifications to my fstab file without any luck:

```
//10.0.1.4/NAS /home/wayne/NAS  smbfs rw,username=,password=,uid=1000 0  0
```

The NAS has no username and password and can be manually mounted in Nautilus.

Comment: What do you get from the following? $ id wayne; ls -al /home/wayne/NAS

Comment: This is what I get with $ id wayne:</br> uid=1000(wayne) gid=1000(wayne) groups=1000(wayne),4(adm),6(disk),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
And this is what I get for ls -al /home/wayne/NAS:</br> total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 wayne wayne 4096 May 18 22:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 43 wayne wayne 4096 Jun  4 17:42 ..

Comment: I had to use `cifs` instead of `smbfs` and add the `_netdev` option.

Answer (score 1):

For an unauthenticated share, get rid of "username=,password=" and replace it with "guest":

```
//10.0.1.4/NAS /home/wayne/NAS smbfs rw,guest,uid=1000 0 0
```

Comment: Tried the above and ran sudo mount -a, but did not work